# Using node.js to use streaming web api's with django

Tags: django, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to write a django application that will use twitter's streaming api. Obviously it can not be done as it is with django since call to twitter will be blocking . Thus i would need to make an asynchronous call to twitter. This led me to think this is a nice opportunity to try out node.js . From what i hear about node.js it seems ideal for making such asynchronous calls. Can someone tell me how i can integrate django and node.js such that all the blocking web api calls can be done using node and all the other aspects of web development can be handled using django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at permanent unix domain sockets connection to proxy content from node.js to python or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the best solution is to use the mediation of a MQ such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) to send messages between the two processes. They seem to be simple to use and very popular.

(Said that, I add that it is an interesting challenge but I would hate to deal with such a complex system. It is all fun and games until somebody loses an eye - and cannot find it out because it is lost in a tightly coupled, ad hoc-driven bunch of code written in two languages using two very different paradigms. If you are planning to create real-life production code, I do not believe such architecture would be a good idea - althoug it is a great idea as an exercise.)

Comment: Usually big projects embrace a lot of deferent technologies twitter PHP & C++, Google Python C++. It is not so dangerous game. But you should to know strength and weak points of each technology that you use.